# Partition resizing and conversion

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted, swap, ext4

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and my partition structure is as follows:

```
 /dev/sdb2   ext2    /              130GB
 /dev/sdb6   swap                    20GB
 /dev/sdb5   ext4    /home          350GB
```

There are two things I want to do without losing my data.

1. I want to convert `/dev/sdb2` from `ext2` to `ext4.
2. I mistakenly assigned a lot of space to `/dev/sdb6` which is a swap partition. So, I want to reduce its size to 3GB and add up the extra 17GB to `/dev/sdb2` which is my root partition.

Can someone please guide me with proper steps so that I do not mess with my existing data. It is essential that not lose my existing data.

I have 4GB RAM; I believe assigning 3GB swap is more than needed. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere, as I am a newbie in Linux.

Comment: I read it here that conversion from ext2 to ext4 can be done without actually re-installing the system. http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/11/convert-ext23-to-ext4/

But, my question is somewhat more complex. I want  to convert as well as resize.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not a good idea - this is the most important sentence in the article : "I want to warn you that you could lose data by doing this so ..." ! :)

Comment: Okay, do I get the surity that my /home partition will remain intact?

Comment: Generally spoken yes, if /dev/sdb5 doesn't get touched, it should stay intact, but working on partitions is not a trivial thing and there is never any guaranty though - and for the part of resizing partitions you can find many already existing answers on Ask Ubuntu. :)